# How can I switch postgres schema's on a per query basis with Hiberante?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, database-schema, multi-tenant

Is it possible for me to set the schema dynamically with Hibernate?

On the same web page (session), I want the ability to alter the schema potentially per query I make.

Is this possible?

i.e. on each DAO method I will pass the name of the schema to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the search path, e.g.:

```
SET search_path TO 'schemaname,public'
```

If you just need this for a single query, you can do that in two ways:

1. Run two queries, one to set the `search_path` and the other for your actual query. If you do this, don't forget to do this in subsequent queries, as they'll be affected too).
2. Change your query so it selects from `schemaname.tablename` rather than plain `tablename`.

Comment: But how to append that to current query?